# How Would I Store The Version/Sequence Number Of A LinearState?

Tags: corda

If I have a LinearState I have the same LinearId every time I save a new version of this State.

What would be the best way to return the version/sequence number of this state?

i.e. when it is created it has version 1 then when it is updated it has version 2 etc

Querying all states and sorting by RECORDED_TIME then looking up the state in the list seems a bit clunky and might not scale very well when you have very large data sets.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the `LinearState` class definition and there is no `version` attribute; so the only way that I think you can achieve this is by doing these steps:

1. Add a `version` attribute to your state.
2. Enforce in your contract:
   a. On `Issue`: `version` should be set to `0`.
   b. On `Update` (or any other command): output `version` = input `version` + 1.
3. Since the notary will enforce that a state cannot be consumed twice; then you will never end up with two updates having the same `version` (because remember that "output `version` = input `version` + 1", and since the input cannot be repeated; then you're good).
4. Create a custom schema for your state, and now you can query by `version`.